# MongoDB 3.4 in PHP: errors passing options

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a ***find*** query where I want to project a single field, plus set up collation options to work with a case-insensitive index.

My query looks like this:

```
$cursor = $collection->find($query, array('projection' => array('fields' => 1), 'collation' => array('locale' => 'en', 'strength' => 2)));
```

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue: Unsupported projection option: projection: { fields: 1 }'

Removing 'projection' and just leaving 'collation' isn't working either, I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue: >1 field in obj: { locale: "en", strength: 2 }'

I have verified I am running on MongoDB 3.4.0.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This structure worked for me but it looks like you will need to add the collation to the projection as the find method only accepts 2 arguments. You do not need to reference the projection in the array the second argument will always be the projection.

```
$projection = array('fields' => 1,'locale' => 'en', 'strength' => 2);

$cursor = $collection->find($query, $projection);
```